# Linking error when using some OpenCV functions "threshold" Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, gcc

When trying to use threshold function in OpenCV 3, there is a linking error that appear like this:

./src/OpenCV.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv9thresholdERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEddi'

make: *** [OpenCV]

note: '_ZN2cv9thresholdERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEddi' is defined in DSO /home/muhammadaly/Documents/opencv-3.0.0/release/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0 so try adding it to the linker command line

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem 5 min ago.
You have missing linker in your project properties.
First of all, follow these instructions to make sure your path and libs added. Also, Bottom of the article there is a YouTube video.
http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/using-opencv-3-0-0-with-eclipse/
As you can notice we have to add everything by hand.

```
cv::threshold(src,dst,128.0,255.0,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

NOTE: These methods already explained in the article that I gave above I am just being specific here for solution.

You are trying to use this function. The first thing to do figures out which .hpp file to include. In Eclipse press ctrl and click the function it will open associated file, in our case this file is `imgproc.hpp`. So add this to your class `#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"`

We haven't done yet. We need to link them too. In Eclipse Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings then  in the Tool Setting tab find GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries. Libraries (-l) add `opencv_imgproc`.

How did I find `opencv_imgproc`:  In console write `pkg-config --libs opencv`. In my case output is like this (it may not be same output because I am using Cuda too.):

> --libs opencv
>   -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_cudabgsegm -lopencv_cudaobjdetect -lopencv_cudastereo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_cudafeatures2d -lopencv_superres -lopencv_cudacodec -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_cudaoptflow -lopencv_cudalegacy -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_cudawarping -lopencv_cudaimgproc -lopencv_cudafilters -lopencv_video -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_cudaarithm -lopencv_core -lopencv_hal -lopencv_cudev

You just need to remove -lo and just use opencv_NAMEOFTHEFILE

These steps have to be done when you use a new function which is not linked yet.